# Tracking e-commerce with Google

Tags: c#, asp.net, e-commerce

I've been asked to add Google e-commerce tracking into my site.  This tracking involves inserting some javascript on your receipt page and then calling it's functions.  From my asp.net receipt page, I need to call one function (_addTrans) for the transaction info and then another (_addItem) for each item on the order.  An example of what they want is [here](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55528)

This is for a 1.1 site.  Can anybody give me a jumpstart on calling these two functions from my c# code-behind?  I can't imagine that I'm alone out there in needing to call Google e-commerce tracking, so I'm hopeful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to build up the required Javascript as a string with something like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()
sb.AppendLine( "<script>" );
sb.AppendLine( "var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker('UA-XXXXX-1');" );
sb.AppendLine( "pageTracker._trackPageview();" );
sb.AppendFormat( "pageTracker._addTrans('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}' );\n", orderId, affiliation, total, tax, shipping, city, state, country );
sb.AppendFormat( "pageTracker._addItem('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}');\n", itemNumber, sku, productName, category, price, quantity );
sb.AppendLine("pageTracker._trackTrans();");
sb.AppendLine( "</script>" );
```

Then register it to appear in the page with

```
Page.RegisterStartupScript("someKey", sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Note also that Page.RegisterStartupScript is obsolete according to MSDN, which recommends using ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript instead.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  However you have to use Page.RegisterStartupScript in ASP.NET 1.1

Answer (score 5):

Here i just wrote an Google Analytics E-Commerce class to dynamically add analytics transactions.

http://www.sarin.mobi/2008/11/generate-google-analytics-e-commerce-code-from-c/

Hope this hope.

Comment: That is fantastic and exactly what I was just starting to write.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In response to stevemegson (first answer) - shouldn't the first parameter into the pageTracker._addItem method be the OrderID, not the itemNumber?

Comment: yes, you are correct.  Should be the orderID in the first parm.

Answer (score 1):

A project i have released allows for easy integration with Google Analytics to fire page views and events through native .net code.

This way you can simply call a method that will log either and event or a page view for you.

I am planning on supporting transaction logging as well over the next few weeks.

It's called GaDotNet and can be found here: http://www.diaryofaninja.com/projects/details/ga-dot-net